# android make bitmap drawable tile in x BUT not stratchable in y

Tags: android, drawable

I'm trying to make bitmap drawable **repeat tile in x**, align this drawable view **bottom** (free space fill by color) so my drawable shouldn't stratch in y.
And I allmoust meet a goal.

Source background image:
[image]

Color to fill free space above this picture in large screens: *#FF5cc8f2*

Here is **first variant**:

```
BitmapDrawable tile = (BitmapDrawable) res
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.background);
        tile.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

        view.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.background));
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(tile);
```

Result:
[image: first variant]

**as you can see I have unwanted white space below clouds.**

**Second variant:**

```
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.background);

            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) AvApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            int width;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                width = display.getWidth();  
            } else {
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                width = size.x;
            }

            int intrinsicHeight = bd.getIntrinsicHeight();
            Rect bounds = new Rect(0,0,width,intrinsicHeight);
            bd.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
            bd.setBounds(bounds);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bounds.width(), bounds.height(), bd.getBitmap().getConfig());
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            bd.draw(canvas);
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

Result:
[image]

**Now image is in the bottom but it's stretched**

Don't care than one screenshot is in landscape orientation and second in portrait - the results are checked in both orientations.

I need your help..

Answer (score 0):

I  would try :

```
BitmapDrawable tile = (BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.background);
tile.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

tile.setGravity(Gravity.bottom)
tile.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.CLAMP); 
// it replicates the edge color if the shader draws outside of its original bounds
//thus you don't even need to set a background color.

view.setBackgroundDrawable(tile);
```

Comment: thank you for answer but the result is the same as my first case. And as I know unfortunately gravity has no effect when tile mode is enabled.

Comment: ooh you're right, it looks like CLAMP is only use for the bottom and right side... strange.